# How to increase a value (BookingID) after each new form post

Tags: php, sql

So I have been told to auto increment my database. How would I do this in a database already created?

```
ALTER TABLE Booking AUTO_INCREMENT=5;
```

Is creating a syntax error

Comment: Primary key has it uses.IF your app needs +1 increment without gaps this is bad coding.

Comment: Search for "auto increment"

Comment: The problem with doing a `MAX()` is that two users might call this exactly at the same time, before trying to use it at the same time. This is called a _race condition_ and will result in a database error, since you'd end up with a duplicate primary key. One of them would succeed and the other would fail.

Comment: For those who are trying to do this in SQlite like I was. It is not possible. 

You will have to recreate your table and then make the PK an AUTOINCREMENT column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The booking ID field should be set to auto-increment.

Comment: I knew there had to be something like this. Cheers :)

Comment: What database are you using, MySQL? You need to specify the field you want to set to auto-increment. If it's already a primary key, you'll need to drop the key first.

Answer (score 0):

The booking ID field should be set to auto-increment.

And then, whenever you insert a row you insert it with an empty value '' for the id.

Later you can find out with "last insert id"

Comment: If you specify column names in your `INSERT` (as you should anyway) then there is no need to supply a value for the `id`.